# Magento2.4.2 Checkout Infinite loop detected When Using Discount Codes

Tags: cart, error, shipping, magento2.4.2, fedex

I am getting a strange error with Magento. When I go to checkout out and do store pickup, set up a coupon code to pay for item and then I hit the checkout button, I get thrown this error page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A red error will appear and it says `Infinite loop detected.`

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Trying to get property 'Message' of non-object in vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 582
```

```
<pre>#1 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->_prepareRateResponse() called at [vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php:554]
#2 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->_getQuotes() called at [vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php:301]
#3 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier->collectRates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#4 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#5 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#6 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Fedex/Model/Carrier/Interceptor.php:23]
#7 Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier\Interceptor->collectRates() called at [vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php:337]
#8 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectCarrierRates() called at [vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping.php:244]
#9 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping->collectRates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping/Interceptor.php:23]
#13 Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\Interceptor->collectRates() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php:1076]
#14 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#15 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#16 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#17 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Interceptor.php:23]
#18 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor->requestShippingRates() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php:1003]
#19 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->collectShippingRates() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Helper/CartFixedDiscount.php:55]
#20 Magento\SalesRule\Helper\CartFixedDiscount->calculateShippingAmountWhenAppliedToShipping() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Helper/CartFixedDiscount.php:163]
#21 Magento\SalesRule\Helper\CartFixedDiscount->getQuoteTotalsForRegularShipping() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Helper/CartFixedDiscount.php:188]
#22 Magento\SalesRule\Helper\CartFixedDiscount->getBaseRuleTotals() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/CartFixed.php:108]
#23 Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CartFixed->calculate() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php:226]
#24 Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier->getDiscountData() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php:202]
#25 Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier->applyRule() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php:134]
#26 Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier->applyRules() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Validator.php:301]
#27 Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator->process() called at [vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Quote/Discount.php:172]
#28 Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount->collect() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php:274]
#29 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collectAddressTotals() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector.php:148]
#30 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector->collect() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#31 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#32 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#33 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/TotalsCollector/Interceptor.php:23]
#34 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector\Interceptor->collect() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php:2015]
#35 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote->collectTotals() called at [vendor/amasty/module-special-promo/Model/DiscountRegistry.php:263]
#36 Amasty\Rules\Model\DiscountRegistry->updateQuoteData() called at [vendor/amasty/module-special-promo/Plugin/LayoutProcessor.php:55]
#37 Amasty\Rules\Plugin\LayoutProcessor->afterProcess() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:146]
#38 Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#39 Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor/Interceptor.php:23]
#40 Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Interceptor->process() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage.php:81]
#41 Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage->getJsLayout() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml:23]
#42 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:23]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:675]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:578]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:555]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:975]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:41]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#80 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#81 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#82 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#83 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:23]
#84 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#85 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#86 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#87 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this. I found the answer on Github

[enter link description here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26786)

This error comes in 2.3.4 or later versions because of

```
if($quote->getTotalsCollectedFlag() === false) { $quote->collectTotals(); }
```

Here, `$quote->collectTotals();` generates error because of recursive call

so, by commenting `// $quote->collectTotals();` or whole if condition it will not go in infinite and code will work properly.

Actually there is no need of `$quote->collectTotals()`; in this file.

Credit to Amit-Hariyani commented on Nov 26, 2020 - GITHUB